# Android , How to create animated icon on status var

Tags: android

I want to put an animated icon (like git etc...) on status bar like GPS ,WİFİ , Battery . My target is notify user , Servis is running background . If My servise is stop animation will stop.How to do that. I don't mind Notification classs. I want to use Android's staff like GPS , CELL etc...

[image: Example]

Comment: The status bar uses a collection of many images, not gifs. Have you done any research into the topic? Tried any code?

Comment: @cricket_007 , I have added image in my question. I want to put that area like WİFi

Comment: I understand what you want. I'm asking what research you've done or searched for to implement this.

Comment: I have searched but most examples are about to Notification